# Complex polynomial: multiplying conjugate root pairs in exponential polar form

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

I have expressed a complex polynomial in terms of its six linear factors, as $(z - x_0)(z - x_1)$ etc., where each x is a root in exponential polar form.

I have been able to express one conjugate pair of factors instead using cartesian form for the root. 
I can then multiply out that pair of factors and express the result in a simpler form.

The other pairs however I do not know how to express in cartesian form, as I am unable to determine the real and imaginary values from the exponential form.

Is there a formula/shortcut/simpler way of multiplying out linear factors corresponding to conjugate pairs of roots while the roots are in exponential form?

Otherwise my result is a large and seemingly messy number of terms that must continue to be multiplied out.

Comment: An example would help. It's not clear what you mean by `express one conjugate pair of factors`.

Comment: Apologies @dxiv. I meant that out of the three pairs of factors (which corresponded to conjugate pairs of roots) I could express only one of them easily in cartesian form. 
This meant I could use $(z - a)(z - \overline a) = z^2 - 2xz + (x^2 + y^2)$.

However, I was unable to simplify the remaining pairs despite knowing that they comprised of conjugates. 
Sorry, I am new to math notation so was not confident in providing the details well via notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conjugate pairs,
\begin{align*}
(z-re^{i\theta})(z-re^{-i\theta}) &= z^2-zre^{i\theta}-zre^{-i\theta} + r^2\\
&= z^2-zr(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}) + r^2\\
&= z^2-zr(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta+\cos\theta-i\sin\theta) + r^2\\
&= z^2-2zr\cos\theta + r^2\\
\end{align*}
Which is purely real, as expected. We can take this further if $re^{i\theta} = a+ib$:
\begin{align*}
z^2-2zr\cos\theta + r^2 &= z^2-2zr\frac{a}{r} + a^2 + b^2\ \mathrm{by\ converting\ to\ cartesian\ form}\\
&= z^2 - 2za + a^2 + b^2\\
&= (z - a)^2 + b^2\ \mathrm{by\ completing\ the\ square}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, the post-square-completion looks really nice now!

Comment: Thank you @Shanye2020,I did not see the equivalence to polar form. This is the simplification I required.